# TCL program to login to a remote server and excute command

Tags: tcl, expect, tclsh

I need to write a TCL program through which I shall be able to login to the remote server and then execute commands on the remote server; also I need to get the output from the remote server.

**EDIT:**

Thanks Kostix for the reply. My requirement says that the TCL script should be able to login to the remote server. I am planning to send the password thru the `expect` mechanism, and after that I am planning to send the commands. My sample code goes like this:

```
set prompt "(%|>|\#|\\\$) #"

spawn /usr/bin/ssh $username@$server
expect {
    -re "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
      #continue to match statements within this expect {}
    }
    -nocase "password: " {
       exp_send "$password\r"
       interact
   }

}
```

I am able to login with this but dont know how to extend this code to send commands. I've tried few methods, but didn't work out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help us help you, could you please provide a bit more information? In particular, how are you wanting the connection to the remote server to be done? (I hope the answer is “`ssh`”…) Also, is using the `expect` program acceptable? It's still Tcl (it's really just an enhanced `tclsh`…)

Comment: Hi Donal , Yes the connection type is ssh and using expect would be great .

Answer (score 0):

Since you're about to use SSH, you might not need neither Tcl nor Expect to carry out this task at all: since SSH stands for "Secure SHell", all you need to do to execute commands remotely is to tell SSH what program to spawn on the remote side after logging in (if you do not do this, SSH spawns the so-called "login shell" of the logged in user) and then SSH feeds that program what you pass the SSH client on its standard input and channels back what the remote program writes to its standard output streams.

To automate logging via SSH, several ways exist:

- Authentication using public keys: if the private (client's) key is not protected by a password, this method requires no scripting at all — you just tell the SSH client what key to use.
- "Keyboard interactive" authentication (password-based). This is what most people think SSH is all about (which is wrong). Scripting this is somewhat hard as SSH insists on getting the password from a "real terminal". It can be tricked to beleive so either through using Expect or simply by wrapping a call to the SSH client using the [`sshpass`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) program.
- Both the SSH client and the server might also support Kerberos-based or GSSAPI-based authentication. Using it might not require any scripting as it derives the authentication credentials from the system (the local user's session).

So the next steps to carry out would be to narrow your requirements:

1. What kind of authentication has to be supported?
2. What program should perform the commands you intend to send from the client? Will that be a Unix shell? A Tcl shell? Something else?
3. Should that remote command be scripted using some degree of interactivity (we send something to it then wait for reply and decide what to send next based on it) or batch-style script would be okay?

Before these questions are answered, the inital question has little sense as it's too broad and hence does not meet stackoverflow format.

Comment: Thanks Kostix for the reply , my requirement says that , the tcl script should be able to login to the remote server , i am planning to send the password thru expect mechanism , and after that i am planning to send the commands ,

Comment: @user2007247, you actually added nothing new compared to your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Commands on the server can be executed either using exec command like this,

```
set a [exec ls -lrta]
puts $a
```

[OR] The expect and execute loop can be continued as above;
I am making  a proc using which linux commands can easily be run;

```
package require Expect

proc ExecCommand {username server password cmd  } {
    spawn /usr/bin/ssh $username@$server
        expect {
            ".*(yes/no)? "               {exp_send "yes\r" ; exp_continue}
            ".*password: "               {exp_send "$password\r";exp_continue}
            ".*$ "                       {exp_send -i $spawn_id "$cmd \r";
                expect {
                    ".*$ " { return 1; close }
                }
            }
        }
}


set result [ExecCommand "admin" "0" "qwerty" "ls"]
if {$result > 0 } {
    puts "Command succesfully executed\n"
} else {
    puts "Failed to execute\n"
}
```